# QTableView model using QComboBox

Tags: python, pyside, qtableview, qcombobox

In this example below I have a simple QTableView which is populated using an AbstractModel. Each row in the table displays information related to a class object called Asset. It has a property called Items that contains a list of strings. I want to know how can i populate the QTableView with a combobox displaying this list of strings for each row.

Secondly when a user changes the item selected in the dropdown, i would like to trigger an event so i can later use it to properly change the color of the colored dot to green or red depending on the object's property called 'Status'

The status would indicate if the Current Version (meaning the latest item in the dropdown list) is the chosen item. If its the last item in the list, meaning the latest item, it would be green, otherwise it's red.

The property 'Active' indicates which item in the dropdownlist is currently selected.

If the status is 0 then it's out dated and if the status is 1 that means the latest version in the dropdownlist is being used.

[image]

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class Asset(object):
    def __init__(self, name, items=None, status=0, active=0):
        self._status = 0
        self._name = ''
        self._items = []
        self._active = active

        self.name = name
        self.items = items if items != None else []
        self.status = status


class AssetModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    attr = ["Name", "Options"]


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._items = []


    def clear(self):
        self._items = []
        self.reset()


    def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._items)


    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.attr)


    def addItem(self, sbsFileObject):
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self._items.append(sbsFileObject)
        self.endInsertRows()


    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return AssetModel.attr[section]
        return QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.headerData(self, section, orientation, role)


    def getItem(self, index):
        row = index.row()
        if index.isValid() and 0 <= row < self.rowCount():
            return index.data(role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
        return None


    def getSelectedItems(self, selection):
        objs = []
        for i, index in enumerate(selection):
            item = self.getItem(index)
            objs.append(item)
        return objs


    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount():
            item = self._items[index.row()]
            col = index.column()
            if 0 <= col < self.columnCount():
                if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                    if col == 0:
                        return getattr(item, 'name', '')
                    if col == 1:
                        return (getattr(item, 'items', []))
                elif role == QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
                    if col == 0:
                        return item
                elif role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
                    if col == 0:
                        status = getattr(item, 'status', 0)

                        col = QtGui.QColor(255,0,0,255)
                        if status == 1:
                            col = QtGui.QColor(255,128,0,255)
                        elif status == 2:
                            col = QtGui.QColor(255,255,0,255)

                        px = QtGui.QPixmap(120,120)
                        px.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
                        painter = QtGui.QPainter(px)
                        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
                        px_size = px.rect().adjusted(12,12,-12,-12)
                        painter.setBrush(col)
                        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 4,
                            QtCore.Qt.SolidLine, QtCore.Qt.RoundCap, QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin))
                        painter.drawEllipse(px_size)
                        painter.end()

                        return QtGui.QIcon(px)


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400,300)

        # controls
        asset_model = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        asset_model.setSortCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        asset_model.setSourceModel(AssetModel())

        self.ui_assets = QtGui.QTableView()
        self.ui_assets.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.ui_assets.setModel(asset_model)
        self.ui_assets.verticalHeader().hide()

        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.ui_assets)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.unit_test()


    def unit_test(self):
        assets = [
            Asset('Doug', ['v01', 'v02', 'v03'], 0),
            Asset('Amy', ['v10', 'v11', 'v13'], 1),
            Asset('Kevin', ['v11', 'v22', 'v53'], 2),
            Asset('Leslie', ['v13', 'v21', 'v23'], 0)
        ]

        self.ui_assets.model().sourceModel().clear()
        for i, obj in enumerate(assets):
            self.ui_assets.model().sourceModel().addItem(obj)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What relationship exists between the selected value of the QComboBox and the status?

Comment: The status would indicate if the Current Version chosen in the dropdown list is the latest item in the list. If its the last item in the list, meaning the latest item, it would be green, otherwise it's red. does that make sense?

Comment: What value of the QComboBox will be the one chosen by default?

Comment: It can default to the first item. I'll eventually make it an optional argument taken when the object is first created

Comment: You must save this state when it is changed with the QComboBox, so you must have an additional attribute in Asset that is the selected item.

Comment: @eyllanesc so how would i set this up in code? That is what i don't know how to do.

Comment: In your comment you indicate that the color is only red or green, but I see an orange color, please edit your question and point out the cases, for example I have the following questions: does status change ?, if the selection of the combobox changes What should change in the view? What do the colors depend on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 tasks:

- Make your model editable because when using the combobox you must edit the values, in addition you must implement new roles to access all the properties of Asset, for it modify the class Asset:

---

```
class Asset(object):
    def __init__(self, name, items=[], active=0):
        self.active = active
        self.name = name
        self.items = items

    @property
    def status(self):
        return self.active == len(self.items) - 1
```

To make an editable model, you must implement the `setData()` method and enable the `Qt.ItemIsEditable` flag:

```
class AssetModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    attr = ["Name", "Options"]
    ItemsRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1
    ActiveRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 2

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._items = []

    def flags(self, index):
        fl = QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.flags(self, index)
        if index.column() == 1:
            fl |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
        return fl

    def clear(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._items = []
        self.endResetModel()

    def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._items)

    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.attr)

    def addItem(self, sbsFileObject):
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self._items.append(sbsFileObject)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return AssetModel.attr[section]
        return QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.headerData(self, section, orientation, role)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount():
            item = self._items[index.row()]
            col = index.column()
            if role == AssetModel.ItemsRole:
                return getattr(item, 'items')

            if role == AssetModel.ActiveRole:
                return getattr(item, 'active')

            if 0 <= col < self.columnCount():
                if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                    if col == 0:
                        return getattr(item, 'name', '')
                    if col == 1:
                        return getattr(item, 'items')[getattr(item, 'active')]
                elif role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
                    if col == 0:
                        status = getattr(item, 'status')
                        col = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red) if status else QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.green)
                        px = QtGui.QPixmap(120, 120)
                        px.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
                        painter = QtGui.QPainter(px)
                        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
                        px_size = px.rect().adjusted(12, 12, -12, -12)
                        painter.setBrush(col)
                        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 4,
                                                  QtCore.Qt.SolidLine,
                                                  QtCore.Qt.RoundCap,
                                                  QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin))
                        painter.drawEllipse(px_size)
                        painter.end()

                        return QtGui.QIcon(px)

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount():
            item = self._items[index.row()]
            if role == AssetModel.ActiveRole:
                setattr(item, 'active', value)
                return True
        return QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.setData(self, index, value, role)
```

- Use a delegate, for it you must overwrite the methods `createEditor()`, `setEditorData()` and `setModelData()` where we created the `QComboBox`, updated the selection of the `QComboBox` with the information of the model, and updated the model with the selection of the `QComboBox`. We also use `paint()` to make the `QComboBox` persistent.

---

```
class AssetDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if isinstance(self.parent(), QtGui.QAbstractItemView):
            self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index)
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        combobox = QtGui.QComboBox(parent)
        combobox.addItems(index.data(AssetModel.ItemsRole))
        combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onCurrentIndexChanged)
        return combobox

    def onCurrentIndexChanged(self, ix):
        editor = self.sender()
        self.commitData.emit(editor)
        self.closeEditor.emit(editor, QtGui.QAbstractItemDelegate.NoHint)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        ix = index.data(AssetModel.ActiveRole)
        editor.setCurrentIndex(ix)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        ix = editor.currentIndex()
        model.setData(index, ix, AssetModel.ActiveRole)
```

Then we establish the delegate and pass it as a parent to the QTableView so that it can be persisted automatically:

```
self.ui_assets.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, AssetDelegate(self.ui_assets))
```

The complete code can be found at the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/5170fb413e38951ec1ab9f6886b77e80).

[image]